how to prevent smsmanager from using phone numbers that cannot receive sms
How to prevent smsmanager from trying to send sms multiple times if there is an error.
Or how to receive and handle the error sending sms
I use a list of phone numbers: "listeDestinataire"
for (int i = 0, listeDestinatairesSize = listeDestinataires.size(); i < listeDestinatairesSize; i++) {
                String phone = listeDestinataires.get(i);
                phone = phone.replace(" ","");
                Log.d("control.envoisms", "************* phone : "+phone);
                SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(phone , null, message, null , null);
            }

But when a phone number is wrong, for example a landline number, smsmanager tries to send several times
